# Maven: Why does my computer always download from http://repo1.maven.org?

Tags: maven

I have two computers. One always downloads from http://repo1.maven.org. While another one downloads from http://repo.maven.apache.org.

Today, I got checksum error like this on the first computer.

```
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected  but is 63801e851fe885601a0bd0eceb6501f7db37e47e for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-archiver-1.0-alpha-6.pom
```

On the second computer, which is using http://repo.maven.apache.org working fine, no checksum errors.

I have been trying to change http://repo1.maven.org to http://repo.maven.apache.org but I cannot find where to change this.

I also wonder why different computers from same network got different repo to download and stuck with that repo forever.

Comment: so what is your maven configuration (settings.xml)?

Comment: nothing just <settings></settings>, it is still using repo1.

Comment: What are the maven versions on the two computers?

Comment: the first is 3.0.3. the second is 3.0.4.

Comment: anyways, this never happened before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was changed with Apache Maven 3.0.4, the related issue is [MNG-5151](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5151)

Comment: Cool that you found this. Anyways, it is weird that they hardcord repo?

Comment: Let's call it default instead of hardcoded :) It there's no default, you should always have to specify a remote repository. I don't think that's user friendly.

Comment: "Not user-friendly" is a mild term :) Since it is defined in the superpom I agree that it is not hardcoded.  I have just deleted the (pluginR)repositories section from superpom in maven-model-builder, my global settings are default(empty) and I emptied my user settings and deleted maven-model-builder from local repo. When I build project right under project build plan in debug output I still see: "[central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]". In terms of official documentation, is there some other place where it is defined?

Answer (score 4):

[Default locations](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Quick_Overview) of your settings files are:

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> - The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> - A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

`M2_HOME` is path to maven installation directory. The defaults can be found in the [maven installation instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi):

- win xp/2k: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.0`
- unix based: `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.0`

or open command prompt/terminal and type:

- win xp/2k: `echo %M2_HOME%`
- unix based: `echo $M2_HOME`

To change the location of your central repository its [mirror can be defined](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html). Open your `settings.xml` and add:

```
<settings>
 ...
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
     <id>myMirrorId</id>
     <name>mirror of a central repo</name>
     <url>http://server</url>
     <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
 ...
</settings>
```

Now when running maven from your project root folder with the debug output (`-X`) you should see in the beggining of your console output:

```
[DEBUG] Using mirror myMirrorId (http://server) for central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
```

The default central repo has `id` central and that's why that is the value of  `mirrorOf` tag. My default central repo is the one you are trying to set.

> I also wonder why different computers from same network got different repo to download.

If you comment everything in your user settings file (leave just the outer `settings` tags) and have default global settings file (which is basically empty) running:

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

will dump practically empty settings. When building project maven still knows the location of the central repo, because every pom file inherits from the [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) and that is where the default central repo URL is defined:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The super pom is located at `$M2_HOME/lib/maven-model-builder-<VERSION>.jar` under `/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml`.

As Robert Scholte informed, as of 3.0.4 the default URL has been changed from `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` to `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`